# iOS code understanding for MobileWifi Framework

Tags: iphone, wifi, signal-strength

I want to implement the code on :

http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MobileWiFi.framework

I am a newbie to IOS development. I have just coded hello world and I need to implement signal strength  from wifi using "Private apis".

I have five files : Appdelegate.h/.m ... ViewController.h/.m and Mainstoryboard.

Can you please tell me, how can I run this code ? Means which code I should keep in which file from the code mentioned in website.

I know, it is silly but I am a new and have to implement signal strength with private apis. I do not wish to publish the code. I hope the code in the website could be implemented.

Realy it would be great if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

**Accessing iPhone WiFi Information via SDK**

According to this it's actually possible since iOS 4.1.

The function is called: CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo()

Hope that helps.

Comment: I saw a website : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/CaptiveNetworkRef/Reference/reference.html


But which code I should run from where ? how shud i keep d code in xcode? Can you pls help me with some detail instructions. It would be realy good for me.

Comment: @smithwilly u set the code in proper way in DidFinishLaunching in AppDel Class and Read the proper Doc.

Comment: @AppleMap.. I want to get signal strength

Comment: Link CoreTelephony.framework in your Xcode project. CODE IS:- int CTGetSignalStrength(); // private method (not in the header) of Core Telephony

- (void)aScanMethod
{
    NSLog(@"%d", CTGetSignalStrength()); // or do what you want
}

Comment: Isnt Core Telephony, getting signal strength of the mobile carrier. I think so. I want wifi signal strength from wifi.